# How can I animate with width set with previous animations?

Tags: css, animation

I have multiple animations in my code.
For one specific image, I am reducing size with two different animations.

```
  &.resize-image-chat1 {
    animation: Squeezein ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-duration: 0.333s;
    @keyframes Squeezein {
      0% { width: 100%;
       }
      100% {width: 1408px; }
    }
  }

 &.resize-image-chat2 {
    animation: Squeezein ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-duration: 0.333s;
    @keyframes Squeezein {
      0% { width: 100%;
       }
      100% {width: 608px; }
    }
  }
```

Now on taking back it to normal size width 100%, i have created one animation like this:

```
&.image-fullscreen{
    animation: zoomin 0.333s ease-in-out forwards;
    @keyframes zoomin {
      0% {;}
      100% {  width: 100%; }
    }
  }
```

But above code is not working. I cant see the animation (image-fullscreen) start from where left from animations (resize-image-chat1 , resize-image-chat2).

What I am supposed to add in 0% in image-fullscreen? I dont want to create two image-fullscreen animations to handle this situation.

Is it possible like this way? Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Jyoti

Answer (score 0):

width initial should work

```
&.image-fullscreen{
    animation: zoomin 0.333s ease-in-out forwards;
    @keyframes zoomin {
      0% {width: initial;}
      100% {  width: 100%; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried initial .. its not working.